# Evaluating an Array for Uniformity

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, boolean

I am trying to evaluate an array for uniformity. I.e. var num =[1,1,1,1,1,] // true or var num =[1,1,2,1,1] = //false.  It could also be for an array of strings.  What I am trying to do is evaluate the whole array and return a single "true" or "false". My code so far evaluates each item in the array and returns the result for each item.  I'm very new to coding and taking classes online and working through problems without cheating!

```
var num = [1,1,3,1,1];
var first = num[0];

num.forEach(function (num, i) {
  if(first === num){
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Instead of logging a `true` or `false` for each answer, create a variable to store the overall answer, then print that when you're done.  Something like this:

```
var num = [1,1,3,1,1];
var first = num[0];
var ans = true;

num.forEach(function (n) {
  if(first !== n){
     ans = false;
  } 
});
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Perfect.  I saw this in some other examples, but could not see how it related.  This works very well and sticks with the logic of my code.  Not sure if this is the best way to evaluate an array for uniformity, but it works and I understand it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var num = [1,1,3,1,1];

var notUni = num.some(function(val, idx, arr){
  return val != arr[0];  // (If arr[0] (1) is the base you're interested in)
});  

console.log( notUni ); // true
```

P.S: `some` will exit as soon it finds a (`true`) mismatch.

Comment: It's better solution than `forEach` because it exits early.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed val != arr[0]; to == and it gives me the correct value.  Although I need to research .some to understand exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function

```
var num = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1];

var result = num.every(n => n == num[0]);
```

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var num = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var result = num.every(n => n == num[0]);

document.write(result);
```